# Buffer Size for execv

Tags: c, bash, pipe, buffer, exec

I have an assignment from university, where I need to read from a pipe a bash command and exec this command. I am thinking of using the execv* because i can create a buffer by splitting with space as delimiter. The problem is that I can't use the STL library and I can't figure out how this buffer should be created because the size of this buffer is variable. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick a suitably high upper limit, do a pass to count first so you know how many you need, or implement your own growable vector by malloc'ing a larger area and copying the data to it any time you need more.

Comment: yeah, i was thinking about the high upper limit but I don't know what the upper limit should be xD. For the growable vector I am thinking that in order to implement that i need to read twice the text,  once for counting and one for adding to buffer.

Comment: You could just pick 128k or something else large enough so that you'll be unlikely to hit it in an assignment (128k was the traditional byte size limit for Linux execve).  If you count first you don't even need to grow it because you already know the size, and that works. Growing would be just appending to a buffer of size N, and if you reach N you just allocate one that's 2*N, copy all the elements, and keep adding to that.

Comment: STL is a C++ library; if you're coding in C, of course you can't use it. What range do you think you'll have to deal with? Would `char buffer[4096];` work? If so, you can use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html). If not, assuming you're on a Unix-like POSIX environment, you can use
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html).  This will get you the data, and you can use
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) or other techniques to parse the buffer afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do only one pipe  commands like below, buffer size 30 is enough,even more

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

But you can support multiple pipe commands, you will get a command like bellow, and your buffer size must be enough it

```
cat index.html  | grep ".com" | grep ".splunk." | cut -d "<" -f2  | cut    -d ">" -f1 | grep ":" | cut -d":" -f2  |  cut -d "/" -f3 | cut -d " " -f1 |  grep ".splunk." | cut -d '"' -f1  | sort | uniq
```

Your buffer size should be 100,I choosed size 100 for my operating system projects like yours, we implemented a terminal, it supports almost everything,multiple pipe,redirection eg...

In addition,I used execvp like below,

```
 execvp(args[0], &args[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there any specific reason that the 100 is enough for piping?

Comment: No,there is no any specific reason,I say my terminal support this threshold value,I think it is enough value,but you  can implement any size, there is no restriction to do it

Comment: Okay, Thanks again!